# WebGL not displaying my triangle despite no errors or warnings

Tags: javascript, glsl, rendering, webgl, webgl2

WebGL not even rendering my triangle that I want its not giving me any errors or anything..

I've tried changing the order of how I do the inputs and rewriting the shader code multiple times.
I'm just trying to draw a triangle.

Here are some snippets of the code I am using

My Vertex Shader

```c
    attribute vec4 a_position;
    attribute vec4 a_color;
    varying vec4 v_color;

    void main()
    {
        v_color = a_color;
        gl_Position = a_position;
    }
```

My Fragment Shader

```c
    attribute vec4 a_position;
    attribute vec4 a_color;
    varying vec4 v_color;

    void main()
    {
        v_color = a_color;
        gl_Position = a_position;
    }
```

the Draw function

```js
function drawTri(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3){
    const a_position = new Float32Array([x1,y1,0,1,x2,y2,0,1,x3,y3,0,1]);

    const a_color = new Float32Array([
      testColor[0],testColor[1],testColor[2],testColor[3],
      testColor[0],testColor[1],testColor[2],testColor[3],
      testColor[0],testColor[1],testColor[2],testColor[3]
    ]);

    gl.useProgram(myShaders.untextured.ProgramInf.program);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, 630, 360);

    //? Bind Positional Data
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,positionBuffer);

    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, a_position, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_position_Location);

    gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_position_Location, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    //? Bind Color Data
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,colorBuffer);

    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, a_color, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_color_Location);

    gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_color_Location, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
```

testColor is defined as

```js
const testColor = [0,0,1,1];
```

Stack Snippet

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); //! getting so mad at this stuff rn that I'm just going to make a fake canvas that renders the real canvas ontop of it.
const gl =
  canvas.getContext("webgl2") ||
  canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl") ||
  canvas.getContext("webgl");
canvas.width = 480;
canvas.height = 360;

gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

//Get Shaders
const myShaders = {
  untextured: {
    Shaders: {
      vert: `
                precision highp float;
                attribute vec4 a_position;
                attribute vec4 a_color;
                varying vec4 v_color;

                void main()
                {
                  v_color = a_color;
                  gl_Position = a_position;
                }
            `,
      frag: `
                precision highp float;
                varying vec4 v_color;

                void main()
                {
                  gl_FragColor = vec4(0,0,1,1);
                }
            `,
    },
    ProgramInf: null,
  },
  /*textured: {
    Shaders: {},
    ProgramInf: null,
  },*/ //todo Later
  createAndCompileShaders: (vert, frag) => {
    //? compile vertex Shader
    const vertShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    try {
      gl.shaderSource(vertShader, vert.trim());
      gl.compileShader(vertShader);
      if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        throw gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertShader);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    //? compile fragment Shader
    const fragShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    try {
      gl.shaderSource(fragShader, frag.trim());
      gl.compileShader(fragShader);
      if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        throw gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragShader);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    //? compile program
    const program = gl.createProgram();
    try {
      gl.attachShader(program, vertShader);
      gl.attachShader(program, fragShader);
      gl.linkProgram(program);
      if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        throw gl.getProgramInfoLog(program);
      }

      gl.validateProgram(program);
      if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.VALIDATE_STATUS)) {
        throw gl.getProgramInfoLog(program);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    return {
      program: program,
      vert: vertShader,
      frag: fragShader,
    };
  },
};

myShaders.untextured.ProgramInf = myShaders.createAndCompileShaders(
  myShaders.untextured.Shaders.vert,
  myShaders.untextured.Shaders.frag
);

const a_position_Location = gl.getAttribLocation(
  myShaders.untextured.ProgramInf.program,
  "a_position"
);
const a_color_Location = gl.getAttribLocation(
  myShaders.untextured.ProgramInf.program,
  "a_color"
);

console.log(a_position_Location, a_color_Location);

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

//predefine penColor's postion so we don't have to call it as much.
const penColor = [0, 0, 1, 1];

const drawTri = (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) => {
  const a_position = new Float32Array([
    x1,
    y1,
    1,
    1,
    penColor[0],
    penColor[1],
    penColor[2],
    penColor[3],
    x2,
    y2,
    1,
    1,
    penColor[0],
    penColor[1],
    penColor[2],
    penColor[3],
    x3,
    y3,
    1,
    1,
    penColor[0],
    penColor[1],
    penColor[2],
    penColor[3],
  ]);

  gl.useProgram(myShaders.untextured.ProgramInf.program);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, 480, 360);

  //? Bind Positional Data

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    a_position,
    gl.STATIC_DRAW
  );

  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    a_position_Location,
    4,
    gl.FLOAT,
    false,
    4 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
    0
  );
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    a_color_Location,
    4,
    gl.FLOAT,
    false,
    4 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
    4 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT
  );

  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_position_Location);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_color_Location);

  gl.useProgram(myShaders.untextured.ProgramInf.program);
  console.log(
    gl.getProgramInfoLog(myShaders.untextured.ProgramInf.program)
  );
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
};

drawTri(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5);
```

Comment: Have you looked at the program info log of the shader? I don't see a precision qualifier.

Comment: I've updated the shaders to have ```precision highp float;``` at the beggining of them

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Add a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then.

Comment: Ok I've added a snippet. I am still learning about this site! I've also modified it a bit to condense the code a bit more and I made the triangle use a solid blue just to see if I could've gotten it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you specified the `stride` for the `vertexAttribPointer`([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/vertexAttribPointer)) incorrectly. In your original code (not the one in the snippet) it'd need to be the size of the attribute in bytes so `NUM_COMPONENTS * BYTES_PER_COMPONENT`, where `NUM_COMPONENTS` is 4 (x,y,z,w) and `BYTES_PER_COMPONENT` is 4 as you're using 32 bit floats. In your newly added snippet code you use an interleaved buffer so it needs to be the size of a whole vertex in bytes.

In addition to setting the proper stride I renamed your buffer variables to reflect that it's a single interleaved buffer.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); //! getting so mad at this stuff rn that I'm just going to make a fake canvas that renders the real canvas ontop of it.
const gl =
  canvas.getContext("webgl2") ||
  canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl") ||
  canvas.getContext("webgl");
canvas.width = 480;
canvas.height = 360;

gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

//Get Shaders
const myShaders = {
  untextured: {
    Shaders: {
      vert: `
                precision highp float;
                attribute vec4 a_position;
                attribute vec4 a_color;
                varying vec4 v_color;

                void main()
                {
                  v_color = a_color;
                  gl_Position = a_position;
                }
            `,
      frag: `
                precision highp float;
                varying vec4 v_color;

                void main()
                {
                  gl_FragColor = v_color;
                }
            `,
    },
    ProgramInf: null,
  },
  /*textured: {
    Shaders: {},
    ProgramInf: null,
  },*/ //todo Later
  createAndCompileShaders: (vert, frag) => {
    //? compile vertex Shader
    const vertShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    try {
      gl.shaderSource(vertShader, vert.trim());
      gl.compileShader(vertShader);
      if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        throw gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertShader);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    //? compile fragment Shader
    const fragShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    try {
      gl.shaderSource(fragShader, frag.trim());
      gl.compileShader(fragShader);
      if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        throw gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragShader);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    //? compile program
    const program = gl.createProgram();
    try {
      gl.attachShader(program, vertShader);
      gl.attachShader(program, fragShader);
      gl.linkProgram(program);
      if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        throw gl.getProgramInfoLog(program);
      }

      gl.validateProgram(program);
      if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.VALIDATE_STATUS)) {
        throw gl.getProgramInfoLog(program);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    return {
      program: program,
      vert: vertShader,
      frag: fragShader,
    };
  },
};

myShaders.untextured.ProgramInf = myShaders.createAndCompileShaders(
  myShaders.untextured.Shaders.vert,
  myShaders.untextured.Shaders.frag
);

const a_position_Location = gl.getAttribLocation(
  myShaders.untextured.ProgramInf.program,
  "a_position"
);
const a_color_Location = gl.getAttribLocation(
  myShaders.untextured.ProgramInf.program,
  "a_color"
);

console.log(a_position_Location, a_color_Location);

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

const vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

//predefine penColor's postion so we don't have to call it as much.
const penColor = [0, 0, 1, 1];

const drawTri = (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) => {
  const vertexBufferData = new Float32Array([
    x1,
    y1,
    1,
    1,
    penColor[0],
    penColor[1],
    penColor[2],
    penColor[3],
    x2,
    y2,
    1,
    1,
    penColor[0],
    penColor[1],
    penColor[2],
    penColor[3],
    x3,
    y3,
    1,
    1,
    penColor[0],
    penColor[1],
    penColor[2],
    penColor[3],
  ]);

  gl.useProgram(myShaders.untextured.ProgramInf.program);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, 480, 360);

  //? Bind Positional Data

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    vertexBufferData,
    gl.STATIC_DRAW
  );

  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    a_position_Location,
    4,
    gl.FLOAT,
    false,
    8 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
    0
  );
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    a_color_Location,
    4,
    gl.FLOAT,
    false,
    8 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
    4 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT
  );
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_position_Location);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_color_Location);

  gl.useProgram(myShaders.untextured.ProgramInf.program);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
};

drawTri(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5);
```